# How to import an excel file for a particular range

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Suppose I have an excel dataset with a range A1:Z5000. I want to import this dataset into sas with the following restriction : I do not want to import the first row and the first few columns (example ,say I want to import from column 14). I do not want to create named ranges in excel or manipulate the excel in any way. Is there any other way out to do this?

Comment: Did you just try telling PROC IMPORT to use the range you want?  Like `K20:Z5000`?

Answer (score 0):

Since the column headers are in row 1 you will have to include that row in the range selector.  You can clip the columns by having the column letter `N` (14th column) in the range selector.   The rows can only be clipped by a subsequent DATA step.

Example:

```
* import all rows from 14th column and to the right;
proc import datafile="C:\temp\Sample.xlsx" replace out=sample_cols;
  range="Sheet1$N1:Z5000";
run;

* sample without first row of data;
data sample_clipped;
  set sample_cols;
  if _n_ > 1;
run;
```